# android how to get phones photo gallery?

Tags: android

I would like to show the phone's photo gallery and when the user selects an image then notify my application on the image selected so I can get that images informations.

is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

u can get the absolute path of your image stored in the Gallery of your phone by

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

here there are different options available. You can use DIRECTORY_PICTURES where all the images are stored in the SD Card.

now u can use this to get your directory file.

u can try this out it works for me